# Raspistill option "--stats"

Tags: raspicam, raspivid

Is this option still available? I have been attempting to use it but I don't see any information on the preview or the final image.

Command used:

```
sudo raspistill -st -ISO 150 -ss 1500000 -e png -o test.png
```

AND

```
sudo raspistill --stats -ISO 150 -ss 1500000 -e png -o test.png
```

- OS: Raspian Jessie (yes I know)
- Sony Picamera for Raspberry Pi

Comment: I would have thought it came out at command line level rather then on the image (EXIF possibly)?  It may help to put O/S version and camera type to help others check in your question.

Comment: source code is here: https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/blob/master/host_applications/linux/apps/raspicam/RaspiStill.c

Comment: @Dougie so that means the feature still exists. I guess now I need to figure out why it won't work for me.

Comment: It seems to be in the cam control Include at https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/blob/master/host_applications/linux/apps/raspicam/RaspiCamControl.c but not in the list of command line options in raspistill - I'm not a c programmer but I think that's where the error is...

Comment: @Andyroo that is odd. I wonder why it was removed from command line. It is still posted on their documentation page on their website.

Comment: I'm not good at github from an iPad but initial search did not show a change.  It may be work logging a fault on there.